# Subtract each row in dataframe by one preceding it

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like so:

```
Day
123
126
210
230
```

and I want to create a new column which subtracts each row by the one preceding it.  I have tried this:

```
df['Diff']=df.set_index('Day').diff()
```

but this doesn't seem to be correct.

My desired output is:

```
Day   Diff
123   0
126   3
210   84
230   20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to set the `Day` as index for that:

```
In [55]: df.Day.diff().fillna(0)
Out[55]:
0     0.0
1     3.0
2    84.0
3    20.0
Name: Day, dtype: float64
```

or if you have only one column:

```
In [56]: df.diff()
Out[56]:
    Day
0   NaN
1   3.0
2  84.0
3  20.0
```

if you need integers:

```
In [58]: df.diff().fillna(0).astype(int)
Out[58]:
   Day
0    0
1    3
2   84
3   20
```